# iOS Simulator changes MacBook tint

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator

XCode Version 4.6.3
MacBook i7 OSx 10.8.4
iOS Sim 6.1

When the iOS simulator launches the tint of my MacBook Pro becomes very blue.
Quit the sim and it returns to normal.

Anyone else experiencing this?
Is there a fix?

Comment: Head over to bugreport.apple.com and file a defect.

Comment: @AlexBrown I did. Just reaching out the the dev community to see if anyone is experiencing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your macbook pro have dual graphics card?

if that is your case your macbook usually works with the intel HD graphics for low tasks
and when you open an app that needs more graphics your macbook switch from intel to nvidia graphics that is the change in color that you notice

when you close that app your macbook switch from nvidia to intel graphics and the color return to normal

seems to be a normal behavior same happen to me

good luck